# Is the following (sketch of) proof correct?

Tags: general-topology

I'm working with the exercise 21 (2º chapter) of Baby Rudin, he asks to give the following proof:

Let $A$ and $B$ be separated subsets of $\mathbb{R}^k$, suppose $a \in A,b\in B$ and define $p(t)=(1-t)a+tb$ for $t\in\mathbb{R}.$ Put $A_0 = p^{-1}(A)$ and $B_0 = p^{-1}(B)$.Prove that $A_0$ and $B_0$ are separated.

What I tried:
(1) Suppose $x\in B_0$, then $p(x)\in B\implies p(x) \notin\bar{A}\implies x\notin p^{-1}(\bar{A})\subseteq \overline{p^{-1}(A)} = \bar{A_0}$.
(2) Then if $x\in \bar{A_0}, x\notin B_0$ since if $x\in B_0$ the above implies $x\notin A_0$ therefore $x\in \operatorname{Bd(A_0)}$ (*)

I'm not sure what to do after (*), I'm considering the possibility that every neighborhood that contains points of $A_0$ and $B_0$ would have a preimage with points of $A$ and $B$ -unless the function $p$ weren't continuous- and then $A$ and $B$ wouldn't be separable.

Still, I checked the proof in the solutions but it seems way longer than the one I sketched. Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x\in B_0=p^{-1}(B)$, then $x\notin p^{-1}(\overline A)\supseteq\overline{p^{-1}(A)}=\overline{A_0}$

You were wrong about the inclusion. It's the other way round: The preimage of the closure contains the closure of the preimage.

Comment: And note that what Stefan says is what you need to conclude $x\in A$, anyway. As you wrote the question, you say $x\notin S$ and $S\subseteq T$, therefore $x\notin T$, which is not a valid conclusion to make. You can't string together any old mathematical operators and conclude something about the first and last one in the string.